# Selecting a jquery-ui-tab based on its id instead of its index?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

Anyone know why the following does not work?

```
$.each( data.d, function( index, item ) {

    // creates the tabs with custom ids
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "add", "page.aspx?id=" + item.id, item.name )
        .find('>ul>li:last')
        .attr('id', 'tab_' + item.id);

    // creates the buttons
    $( "#buttons" ).append( "<input type='button' id='buttona" + item.id + "' value='" + item.name + "'>" );

    // link buttons with tabs
    $( "#buttona" + item.id ).live('click', function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "select" , "#tab_" + item.id );
    });

});
```

I am trying to assign `id`'s to the tabs, then select the tabs using their `id`'s.

The above does nothing when a button is clicked and it returns no errors at all.

It works fine when using the `index` as shown below, but I need to use an `id` for various reasons:

```
$.each( data.d, function( index, item ) {

    // creates the tabs
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "add", "page.aspx?id=" + item.id, item.name );

    // creates the buttons
    $( "#buttons" ).append( "<input type='button' id='button" + index + "' value='" + item.name + "-" + index + "'>" );

    // link buttons with tabs
    $( "#button" + index ).live('click', function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "select" , index );
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method to get the index of the tab from the id of its header:

```
$("#button" + item.id).live("click", function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs("select", $("#tab_" + item.id).index());
});
```

Since `index()` is called without arguments in the code above, it will return the index of the element relative to its siblings, i.e. the other tab headers.

Answer (score 0):

you can switch the tabs with the id of the tab:

```
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();

$("button").click(function() {
    $tabs.tabs( "select", "#tabs-6" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that .index() returns an index from 1 so that if I have 3 tabs and want to select the third one, I should return :

```
$("#button" + item.id).live("click", function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs("select", $("#tab_" + item.id).index()-1);
});
```